# How to create a Task<> I can complete manually

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

In unit testing a component I need to verify how a component reacts to Tasks being completed at various times.

How do I create a `Task<>` that I can resolve at will?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use a [`TaskCompletionSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create a fully 'manual' task.

> Represents the producer side of a Task unbound to a delegate,
>   providing access to the consumer side through the Task property.

Hand out the the completion source's `Task` property to the consumer, and call `SetResult` on it (at will) to complete the task. Note that you also have `SetCanceled` and `SetException` to represent cancellations and failures, respectively.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know when exactly continuations will run? When `SetResult` is called? At some time later? Is there a way to control this?

Comment: It's not thread-specific - the `Set***` methods can be called on any thread, and the object itself is thread-safe. It also provides the `TrySet***` family of methods to deal with races.

Comment: The continuations will run when the task finishes (as determined by the task-state filter on the continuation, if appropriate).