# How can a child thread wait for something in the main thread to complete?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

Usually the question is for the main thread to wait for child thread which I can use `await` on the `Task`.

But I have a situation where the child thread must wait for some method in the main thread to complete before continuing. How to make this communication possible?

```
public void MainThread()
{
    Task t = Task.Run(ChildThread); //not using await because we want to continue doing work that must be only on the main thread
    WorkA();
    WorkB();
    ???
    WorkC();
}

public async Task ChildThread()
{
    WorkD();
    ???
    Need_WorkB_ToBeCompletedBeforeThisOne();
}
```

`WorkA` `WorkB` `WorkC` are all necessary to be on the main thread. All of them would be issue indirectly from the child thread in my real code because child thread need them done but could not do it because of thread restriction.

I have a way for my child thread to tell main thread to do work already (so I simplify the code to what you see here, as soon as the task start the work will immediately follows) but I need some way for the issuer (child thread) to know about the progress of those commands.

PS. Thanks to answers from this thread I have created `CoroutineHost` for Unity, which you are able to `await` the `yield IEnumerator` method that you can issue to your main thread to do from any of your child threads : https://github.com/5argon/E7Unity/tree/master/CoroutineHost

Comment: Why not have `ChildThread()` only do `WorkD()` and return, then `await WorkB()` in `MainThread()` and have a call to `Need_WorkB...()` after that?

Comment: My bad, actually WorkA to C would be issued by the `ChildThread()` (because there is a software restriction if WorkA to C was execute on the thread other than the main thread) I want a way so that after the issue, `ChildThread()` can get some kind of indication of how things going in the main thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for a "signal". Since the child is asynchronous and the signal is used only one time, a `TaskCompletionSource<T>` would work nicely:

```
public void MainThread()
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>(); // Create the signal
  Task t = Task.Run(() => ChildThread(tcs.Task)); // Pass the "receiver" end to ChildThread
  WorkA();
  WorkB();
  tcs.SetResult(null); // Send the signal
  WorkC();
}

public async Task ChildThread(Task workBCompleted)
{
  WorkD();
  await workBCompleted; // (asynchronously) wait for the signal to be sent
  Need_WorkB_ToBeCompletedBeforeThisOne();
}
```

See recipe 11.4 "Async Signals" in [my book](https://stephencleary.com/book/) for more information. If you need a "signal" that can become set and unset multiple times, then you should use [`AsyncManualResetEvent`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx).

Comment: Not sure why the `Task.Run` wrap around ChildThread, could you explain?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: It was in the question code. I assume the `Task.Run` is necessary because `ChildThread` has to run in a different thread.

Comment: So, that means that if you don't wrap with `Task.Run` it doesn't run on a different thread? I was under the impression by some post that by it being an `async Task` it ran on a different thread already

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: No, `async` doesn't run code on a different thread.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine something like this if WorkB was a Task:

```
public void MainThread()
{
    Task workB = WorkB();
    ChildThread(workB); // you don't need to use Task.Run here, the task is ran automatically
    WorkA();
    WorkC();
}

public async Task ChildThread(Task otherTaskToWait)
{
    WorkD();
    await otherTaskToWait;
    Need_WorkB_ToBeCompletedBeforeThisOne();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but `WorkB` cannot be on the other thread due to restriction of the program (Unity). If `WorkB` did really became a Task by `Task workB = WorkB();` that would mean we have already put it in the other thread? (so we can await it)

Comment: @5argon if you are using Unity, are you using the experimental 2017 version? Otherwise, Unity doesn't know about Task's. And I was assuming that workb could run on a different thread

Comment: @5argon The fact that an operation is asynchronous doesn't mean it's using another thread.  Running code in another thread is just one way of making an operation asynchronous.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes I am using Unity and already choose the experimental .NET 4.6. All of Work A, B, and C are all related to creating objects or firing `UnityWebRequest` and it complains if I try to start them from other thread. I have managed to make the other thread tells main thread to start them, but I need a way to wait for those commands.

Comment: @5argon regardless of the problem right now, I'd suggest you to wait since I find it likely that Unity will allow the UnityWebRequest to run on different threads in the future (otherwise, why even allow different threads...?) The answer by Stephen Cleary is what you are looking for then

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Currently Unity already complain if I do `UnityWebRequest.Post` outside of main thread. But I want a child thread to make this web request so I have the main thread do it for me. What I actually want for real is for the child thread to know when this `UnityWebRequest` finished posting.. but the question might be too specific so I generalized it. Yes, `TaskCompletionSource` looks like a way to go after the main thread finished `yield`ing the `UnityWebRequest`, after I finished trying this I will accept the answer.

Comment: @Servy If possible I am curious to know what the inside of `WorkB();` in `Task workB = WorkB();` would look like to return a `Task` if not from functions like `Task.Run(...)`? (Which spawn a new thread) How can an asynchronous `Task` be created by other means?

Comment: @5argon The most common would be either an IO operation, or composite operations that are themselves composed of one or more other asynchronous operations, that themselves may not involve running code on another thread.  There are also other less common possibilities.

Comment: @Servy I think he referred to how the code would look like (signature, example contents)

Comment: Oh, I just read about manually creating your own `Task` at will in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27891253/how-to-create-a-task-i-can-complete-manually and realize that it is actually Stephen Cleary's answer. It's fine now I think. (With this, actually this answer is almost equal to Stephen's answer by making the inside of `WorkB` produces `TaskCompletionSource` -> `Task`)