# Await and .Result keeps awaiting forever

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Why the following program never ends?

```cs
namespace Example
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var result = await  new Program().test();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        private async Task<(int, string)> test()
        {
            var result =  new Task<(int, string)>(() => (10, "sssss"));
            return (result.Result.Item1, result.Result.Item2);
        }
    }
}
```

What I have noticed is that `result.Result` or writing `await new Task<(int, string)>(() => (10, "sssss"));` will let the program keep awaiting forever!!

Comment: mixing `async await` and blocking calls like `.Result` causes deadlock

Comment: No need to await if nothing in there is async. just return `Task.FromResult` with your desired value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mixing `async await` and blocking calls like `.Result` can causes deadlocks

No need to await if nothing in there is async. Just return [`Task.FromResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult) with your desired value

```
private Task<(int, string)> test() {
    (int, string) value =  (10, "sssss");
    return Task.FromResult(value);
}
```

It will return a successfully completed task with the specified result.

Comment: Thanks a lot, why async and await works with Task.FromResult like in the following example 

        private async Task<(int, string)> test()
        {

            (int, string) value = (10, "sssss");
            return await Task.FromResult(value);
        }

Comment: It works but is not needed. When you await an already completed task it will just continue since there is no need for another thread

Comment: Thanks again 
if I write such a line 
var task=  new Task<(int, string)>(() => (10, "sssss")); 

is there away to complete this task and return its values so I get similar result to Task.FromResult ?  sorry I am a bit new and trying to understand.

Comment: You want to avoid creating tasks manually. That is what those helper methods are for. If you have `new Task` in your code it is usually a sign that you are doing something wrong or something you shouldn't be doing.

Comment: Humm, excuse my curiosity! do you have any article to learn how to create tasks manually and work with them?

Comment: This guy's blog has a wealth of knowledge about async await https://blog.stephencleary.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot again and the below also seems helpful 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27891253/how-to-create-a-task-i-can-complete-manually
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=net-5.0

Comment: Yes TaskCompletionSource allows you more control in manually completing a Task

Answer (score 4):

The `Task` constructor creates a "cold" task, a task that has not been started. If you `await` such a task, the `await` will never complete, because the task will remain forever in the [`Created`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus) status, and will never transition to the `RanToCompletion` status. To start a task that was created cold, you must call its [`Start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.start) or `RunSynchronously` methods, preferably passing the `TaskScheduler.Default` as argument:

```
private Task<(int, string)> TestAsync()
{
    var task = new Task<(int, string)>(() => (10, "sssss"));
    task.Start(TaskScheduler.Default);
    return task;
}
```

Creating cold tasks by using the `Task` constructor is an advanced technique that is used rarely in practice. The common way to create [delegate-based tasks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html) is by using the static [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) method, that creates hot tasks. The method below is functionally identical¹ with the previous method:

```
private Task<(int, string)> TestAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(() => (10, "sssss"));
}
```

Be aware that both methods above are considered bad practices, for reasons explained [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/).

¹ <sub>Actually not exactly identical. The second example starts a task having the `TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach` configuration. More info about this can be found [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/).</sub>